# Where did ViewLocationExpanderContext.IsPartial go?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

In Core MVC if you want the razor view engine to look for views in places other than the default locations then a new ViewLocationExpander can be added in the `ConfigureServices` method in the startup.cs like so

```
services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options => {
      options.ViewLocationExpanders.Add(new ViewLocationExpander());
});
```

Where the `ViewLocationExpander` class implements `IViewLocationExpander`.  That class typically has access to the `ViewLocationExpanderContext`, and in RC1 that context contained an `IsPartial` property.  This property was useful if the location expander wanted to specify different view locations for partial views than regular views.

I see that in RC2 this `IsPartial` property is gone.  However, I do see that there is a `IsMainPage` property but I can't find any documentation on it.

Does anyone know if the property basically just the inverse of the old `IsPartial` property?

Comment: Yes - it's essentially the inverse https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/commit/3be6167aa093033a71ab6822fbc9199b4731a030. https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor/ViewLocationExpanderContext.cs#L66-L69

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `IsMainPage` property is as you've said - the inverse of `IsPartial`. As Pranav has pointed out in the comments, you can see the commit and reasoning for the change [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/commit/3be6167aa093033a71ab6822fbc9199b4731a030).

Glad to see I'm not the only one that was caught out by this change!